# UIImageView will not animate with an image based animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have 8 `UIImageView`s that were created in the storyboard that I am trying to animate with an image based animation, but for some reason the images won't animate.

`viewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RandomImages;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// Outlets foe the dice
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage0;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieImage7;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *MenuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *rollTargetButton;

@property (strong, nonatomic) RandomImages *randomImages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *diceOutletArray;

- (void) rollDice;

@end
```

`viewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RandomImages.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize dieImage0;
@synthesize dieImage1;
@synthesize dieImage2;
@synthesize dieImage3;
@synthesize dieImage4;
@synthesize dieImage5;
@synthesize dieImage6;
@synthesize dieImage7;
@synthesize diceOutletArray;
@synthesize rollTargetButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.randomImages = [[RandomImages alloc] init];

    self.rollTargetButton.hidden = YES;

    self.diceOutletArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.dieImage0, self.dieImage1, self.dieImage2, self.dieImage3, self.dieImage4, self.dieImage5, self.dieImage6, self.dieImage7, nil];

     // Animation for rolling dice
    for (UIImageView *dieImages in self.diceOutletArray) {
        dieImages.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die5"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die6"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die1"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die4"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die3"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die5"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die2"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die1"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die6"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die3"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die5"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die2"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die3"], nil];
        dieImages.animationDuration = 1.0f;
        dieImages.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) rollDice{
    self.diceOutletArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.dieImage0, self.dieImage1, self.dieImage2, self.dieImage3, self.dieImage4, self.dieImage5, self.dieImage6, self.dieImage7, nil];

    // Randomly set the image of the dice
    for (UIImageView *numberImage in self.diceOutletArray) {

        numberImage.image = [self.randomImages randomNumber];
        [numberImage startAnimating];

    }

}

/* Motion functions *****************************************************************************************/

- (void) motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
- (void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        [self rollDice];
        NSLog(@"There was a bump!: Line 85");
    }
    NSLog(@"Motion Ended: Line 87");
}

- (void) motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

/* Roll Button **********************************************************************************************/

- (IBAction)rollDiceButton {
    [self rollDice];
    NSLog(@"Ouch! Somebody poked me!: Line 97");
}


/* Segues **************************************************************************************************/



@end
```

`RandomImages.m`

```
#import "RandomImages.h"

@implementation RandomImages
@synthesize diceImages;

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Array of dice for the randomNumber method
        self.diceImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicey-die1"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicey-die2"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicey-die3"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicey-die4"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicey-die5"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicey-die6"], nil];
    }
    return self;
}


// Random dice number method
- (UIImage *)randomNumber {
    int random = arc4random_uniform((int)self.diceImages.count);
    return [self.diceImages objectAtIndex:random];
}

@end
```

`RandomImages.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RandomImages : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *diceImages;

- (UIImage *) randomNumber;

@end
```

Selecting a random image does work.

I did try this in my `rollDice` method and nothing changed:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        numberImage.image = [self.randomImages randomNumber];
        [numberImage startAnimating];
    });
```

Comment: Why do you set both `animationImages` and `image` on each image view? You should only use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Were am I doing that? Are you talking about the for loop, were the ImageViews are assigned the name 'dieImages'? (Did I say that correctly?)

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you set `animationImages` for all of the image views. Then in `rollDice` you set `image` for all of the image views.

Comment: do you have 7 dice on the screen? I am a bit lost as to what you are hoping to do here

Comment: @MarkGilchrist, I have a grid of 8 dice ( dieImage0 - dieImage7 ). I want to animate them, then give the UIImageView a random selected image.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have a random image that I am assigning the the ImageView, then I animate the ImageView. I did the same thing before in Swift, and it worked.

Comment: When you call the function does it just jump to the random images or does nothing happen?

Comment: It just jumps to the random images.

Comment: @MarkGilchrist, is it possible that the issue is that the image views were created in the storyboard?

Comment: No, try making sure it's run on the main thread. Dispatch_async get_main_que

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a typo.
I've created the project and your code working ok.
I'll share my local project if you want.

Look out for image file names.
 
`@"dicey-die..."` and `@"dicy-die..."`

I believe `@"dicy-die..."` is not added in the project.

**Update:**

github list for my project
https://github.com/rishi420/TestAnimationImage/tree/master

Comment: Yes, I want to see your project.

Comment: @CalebKleveter - answer updated. feel free to change this repo.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have ONE UIImageView. Not 8.

The whole point of animated images it that it uses one UI element (a UIImageView) and then loops through the images.

```
self.myONEImageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die5"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die6"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die1"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die4"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die3"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die5"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die2"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die1"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die6"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die3"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die5"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die2"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dicy-die3"], nil];
```

Comment: then what do I do if I want to animate 8 UIImageViews? I am trying to animate "dice".